# Import stackapi module recognization

Tags: python

I installed stackapi using pip successsfully

I try to run the following code:

```
from StackAPI import StackAPI, StackAPIError
try:
    SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key=SETTINGS['xxxxxxx'])
    SITE.max_pages=100
    SITE.page_size=1000000000
    post = SITE.fetch('posts', ids=[59115355, 2901002], sort='activity', order='desc')
except StackAPIError as e:
    print(e.message)
```

But I receive this error:

> from StackAPI import StackAPI, StackAPIError
>
> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StackAPI'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this was part of the issue, see further details in the comments below. Leaving the question since it has more information.

Mind the capitalization, the correct import line would be:

```
from stackapi import StackAPI, StackAPIError
```

Comment: does the error message now have `stackapi` in lowercase? if so it could be due to virtual environment (if any). The correct capitalization for module names is usually all lowercase.

Comment: yes it is now this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stackapi'`

Comment: I think the stackapi module is not installed in the environment where you are running, if so the command `help("modules stackapi")` will not return any results, and you should try to install via `pip install stackapi` again

Comment: I used pip to install it. If I use help I receive this `stackapi
stackapi.stackapi
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda insta
ll m2w64-toolchain`
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to exe
cute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Pyth
on implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warnin
g, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS fu
nctions.`

Comment: I don’t know about that error but as far as I know it should find the module... hopefully someone else can figure it out, I’ll leave the answer for now for reference of what was already tried (there was after all an issue that was fixed in the answer but another appeared). If a solution is found or this is inappropriate, leave a comment here and I’ll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The alias used in the import function should be outside the actual code as shown below:

```
from StackAPI import StackAPI, StackAPIError as e
try:
    SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key=SETTINGS['xxxxxxx'])
    SITE.max_pages=100
    SITE.page_size=1000000000
    post = SITE.fetch('posts', ids=[59115355, 2901002], sort='activity', order='desc')
except:
    print(e.message)
```